# Trying to parse JSON that is nested using Gson

Tags: android, gson

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public static final String json = "[{'quotes':[{'quote':'sdfsdfsdfdsf!','source':'sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'},{'quote':'sdfsdfsdfsdf!','source':'-sdfsfsdf'},{'quote':'Isdfsf','source':'sfsfsf'}]}]";

Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

       Event event = gson.fromJson(array.get(0), Event.class);


        System.out.println("Using Gson.fromJson() to get:" + event.getQuotes());
```

And here is the Event class:

```
static class Event {
        private JsonArray quotes;
        private Event(JsonArray quotes) {
        this.quotes = quotes;

        }
        public JsonArray getQuotes() {
            return quotes;
        }
        public void setQuotes(JsonArray quotes) {
            this.quotes = quotes;
        }

      }
```

Essentially, I'm trying to parse out the content. Grab the "quotes" and place the contents in another JsonArray, which it is isn't it? However, the app crashes because I dont think it works this way.

Any ideas? I've been pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: what if it can be done using native JSON Classes? Pls let me know so i suggest a solution.

Comment: Can you show us what error your getting. What does the logcat say?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string is invalid, just check it here: http://jsonlint.com/

So First of all your JSON string should be like:

```
[{"quotes":[{"quote":"sdfsdfsdfdsf!","source":"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"},
{"quote":"sdfsdfsdfsdf!","source":"-sdfsfsdf"},{"quote":"asdfsf","source":"sfsfsf"}]}]
```

And if you want to store in String variable then:

```
public static final String json = "[{\"quotes\":[{\"quot\e":\"sdfsdfsdfdsf!\",\"source\":\"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf\"},
    {\"quote\":\"sdfsdfsdfsdf!\",\"source":\"-sdfsfsdf\"},{\"quote\":\"asdfsf\",\"source\":\"sfsfsf\"}]}]";
```

JSON Parsing using Native Classes (not by using GSON or any API):

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(json);
JsonArray array = obj.getJsonArray("quotes");

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
   JsonObject subObj = array.getJsonObject(i);
   String strQuotes = subObj.getString("quote");
   String strSource = subObj.getString("source");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to parse out the content. Grab the "quotes" and place the contents in another JsonArray

I'd take a different approach to handling this data structure, unless there is some compelling reason to do otherwise.

Since use of Gson is possible, then use it for what it's good at, and forget about handling JSON API components like JsonArray and JsonObject.  Gson is good for very simply binding JSON data to a Java data structure.  So, I might take an approach similar to the following, to then allow for simple manipulation of a Java data structure free of JSON concerns.

**Input JSON**

```
[
    {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "I never think of the future. It comes soon enough.",
                "source": "Albert Einstein"
            },
            {
                "quote": "A riot is the language of the unheard.",
                "source": "Martin Luther King, Jr."
            },
            {
                "quote": "A hero is someone who understands the responsibility that comes with his freedom.",
                "source": "Bob Dylan"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Java Code**

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Event[] events = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), Event[].class);
    System.out.println(events[0].quotes[0].quote);
    System.out.println(events[0].quotes[0].source);
  }
}

class Event
{
  Quote[] quotes;
}

class Quote
{
  String quote;
  String source;
}
```